# DNS Fault - missing entries

Tags: windows, domain-name-system

Problem:- 2012 DC GC Server - DNS appears with no sub folders.

Background:- Single DC, 2012 R2. Unable to add new entries to DNS - accepts the change but press F5 to refresh, entry disappears.

My DNS looks like this [DNS Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VvXTq.png)

It's missing all the sub entries, other PC's and so forth.

NSLOOKUP works fine can resolve anything.
PING works fine too.
No issues with the network all works fine.
DCDIAG - no faults found.

Server restarted to no avail.  DNS still has the same problem.

Comment: Did you check the DNS event log for entries with that record?

Comment: 1. - 4521.... >> The description for Event ID ( 4521 ) in Source ( Microsoft-Windows-DNS-Server-Service ) cannot be found. Either the component that raises this event is not installed on your local computer, or the installation is corrupted. You can install or repair the component on the local computer, or contact the component manufacturer for a newer version.

If the event was saved from another computer or forwarded from a remote computer, you might have to include display information with the events when saving them or when setting up the forwarding s 9605, TrustAnchors.

Comment: 2 - 5504 .... >> The description for Event ID ( 5504 ) in Source ( Microsoft-Windows-DNS-Server-Service ) cannot be found. Either the component that raises this event is not installed on your local computer, or the installation is corrupted. You can install or repair the component on the local computer, or contact the component manufacturer for a newer version.

If the event was saved from another computer or forwarded from a remote computer, you might have to include display information with the events when saving them or when setting up the forwarding s 198.143.63.103

Comment: How often are you getting that 4521? Any other 4000 messages? Does any other DNS server have the full zone? You might have to reset it.

Comment: 4521 - every 3 mins.  No other DNS server exists.  How would I reset, and will it damage Active Directory?

Answer (score 1):

4521 is a failure to load an AD integrated DNS zone. Since it's occurring every 3 minutes, I doubt it has successfully loaded some its last reboot.

If no other DNS servers are viable, you should rebuild the whole DNS infrastructure following this guide: [How to reinstall a dynamic DNS Active Directory-integrated zone](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/294328/how-to-reinstall-a-dynamic-dns-active-directory-integrated-zone)

Comment: Hi,  Thanks for the message.  Is this relevant to a 2012 server?  Doesn't seem so?

Comment: Yes both DNS and AD are very mature products. At the bottom it was last reviewed in 2009, obviously after Server 2008 was released. Not much has changed. The key is to delete the physical DNS file and remove the old DNS objects from inside AD. After removing the legacy objects and files, remove and re-add the DNS role.

Comment: Ok thank you.  Will it stop Active Directory from working?

Comment: Not AD directly. AD uses DNS for replication, since there's no other Domain Controllers to replicate to, it's a non-issue. It will stop all other DNS clients from resolving new requests, existing requests will stay in the respective systems DNS cache. Since it's just one server, the rebuild should be quick enough that service distortion would be minimal, I imagine, of course that's a business decision for your organization to make.

Comment: Thanks.  Will it auto populate all the sub folders etc?  i.e _sites _tcp _udp _DomainDnsZones _ForestDnsZones and so forth?

Comment: Yes. Once the DC registers it's SRV records after restarting the netlogon service.

Comment: I've actioned the above, and it still isn't working.  I have ran a DNS DCDIAG test;-

Comment: How do I attach a log file?

Comment: I'm hoping to start a chat room if we keep posting in the comments. Are you still getting the 4521 errors? Did the _msdcs zone get created? Is DNS working?

Comment: DNS isn't working.  Nothing got created.  I tried to create the zone again, and nothing populated even after several reboots. Yes I am still getting 4521 errors.   - Surely we have to 'chat' in order to potentially solve the problem?

Comment: What I would do is remove the DNS role again. Then follow the screen shots in this blog https://blogs.msmvps.com/acefekay/2009/09/02/using-adsi-edit-to-resolve-conflicting-or-duplicate-ad-integrated-dns-zones/ to delete all traces of the old zones from the 3 partitions. Then re add the DNS role again

Comment: I've just done this, however no duplicate entries.  Upon installing DNS still  no zone.  Manually created the zone.  Still getting errors.  What happens is this;-  Add an entry say 'A' record, remains on the screen until I press F5 (refresh).  Then disappears. ADSI EDIT - DomainDNS......shows the entry but it doesn't show within DNS.

Comment: I wasn't concerned about dupes, I just wanted to ensure that the entire zone was deleted from all 3 partitions before the reinstall. I'm confirming, this is on a Domain Controller correct, and it's set as an Active Directory Integrated Zone as well? There's got to be other errors or issues. Try changing it to a StandAlone zone and allow unsecured updates.

Answer (score 0):

The problem all along was........... FILTER applied looking for an object I've never heard of, and doesn't exist. This would explain the vanishing after a refresh, yet all objects existing under ADSI EDIT -
 Domain DNS section